# How do you kill ground troops with a starfighter?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I enjoy flying starfighters like the X-Wing and TIE fighters in ship-to-ship combat, but have a hard time hitting anything on the ground without crashing. This is because the ship only shoots in the direction it's flying, and down is a bad direction to be flying.

I know this can be done consistently, as I've been in games that were completely dominated by fighters shooting everything that moves.

How is this done? Is there some special trick or strategy that makes it easier?

Comment: `down is a bad direction to be flying.` lol

Comment: You just have to [miss the ground](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Flying). Easy.

Comment: isn't that how Ace Combat machin gun works ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's any simple trick, just a few strategies that can help, and getting good at those strategies can *sometimes* give you that 30/2 K/D spread you're looking for. Here are the strategies that have helped me get better at using ships for something other than just dogfighting:

- **Choose your view.** Some pilots prefer the cockpit view for targeting purposes. Some prefer the third-person camera for a bigger field of view. Try both and see what feels more comfortable.
- **Strafing runs** seem to work better for me than dive-bombs. As you have perceptively noted in your post, down is a pretty bad direction to be flying. Maybe try a more gradual dive, varying your speed to find a comfort level that keeps you from being a sitting duck, as well as keeping you from zipping past your objective (or, more often, into the ground.
- Some ships have **missiles**, which can be fired without locking onto a target. With a little practice, you can use them as a straight-line projectile. (Interesting note, the Ion rocket launcher, which only locks on to vehicles, can be used to hurt ground troops if theyre caught standing between you and your vehicle target).
- **Some maps are more conducive to air-to-ground combat**. I find Hoth to be the easiest for seeing and attacking ground troops, either way, it's all about your comfort level navigating the map, and gaining a familiarity with its features and choke points.

All in all, I don't think there is a tried-and-true method or quick answer (unless I've missed it as well). I think it's mainly about practice and finding your own play style (even within the arena of air-to-ground combat). But, as I'm sure you know,  **pulling your throttle back, sighting up on a map's common choke-point from a long distance away, and unleashing the fury of your blasters until you cover that long distance** will undoubtedly serve you well. To be consistent with it will most likely just take a lot of practice, and a lot of rage-inducing crashes.

Comment: I have difficulty even seeing ground troops while zipping past in an A-Wing. Do you think people are just shooting at spots where someone *ought* to be?

Comment: @DCShannon I'd say that's probably the case more often than not. Unless you have a 60 inch tv, even spotting an AT-ST from the air is pretty tough sometimes. There are some geographical features that I regularly shoot at, and wait to see if my reticle showed a hit register. It's harder visibility than Battlefied 4, I will say that; but even BF4 took some skill to kill ground troops with a jet. It's a shame there is no heli equivalent in Battlefront.

Comment: @DCShannon yep, that's why you turn your lights off when the air raid alarms go off

Comment: If you play a map enough you tend to notice patterns.  Novice players tend to have problems adapting to the situation, hence you can predict how they move about on the map.

Answer (score 1):

1. Slow your ship to its' slowest speed
2. Don't dive bomb straight into the ground, make a gradual descent
3. From the air, individual players are hard to see. Their laser shots, however, are not. Look for where crossfire is happening and aim where you think the opposing team is shooting from
4. Many maps have corridors or very well-traveled areas where a ship can often just shoot at from a distance and do damage (especially on Sullust)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to practice a lot, play a lot of fighter squadron, and then get all the ships you can in supremacy.